# Add wrapper to already opened stream

Tags: php, http, stream, zlib

You can open a gzipped HTTP resource like this:

```
$file = 'compress.zlib://http://www.example.com/myarchive.gz';
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
```

But supposing you don't know a resource is gzipped until after you open and fetch its meta data with `stream_get_meta_data`, how can you add the `compress.zlib` after you've already `fopen`'d the resource?

Comment: is [`gzopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php) not an alternative you could use?

Comment: @Darren No. I'm actually passing quite a few options to the 4th param of `fopen` (the context), which gzopen doesn't support. Not that it makes much of a difference; I think `compress.zlib://` is more or less equivalent to `gzopen`. Both actually *do* work on non-compressed files, but it's not *just* gzipped files I'll be fetching so I want to conditionally add a wrapper based on the Content-Encoding which I don't know until after the headers come through.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the **curl** to read a file?
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com/myarchive.gz'
  , CURLOPT_HEADER => 0
  , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
  , CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'
));
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I'm specifically trying to avoid cURL, but you also missed the premise of the question. I don't know the encoding until I get the headers back.